# Folders missing after packaging with electron-packager

Tags: azure, electron, azure-storage, electron-packager

### Introduction

We have an electron app, which uses azure-storage for getting documents from our azure blob.
Everything seems to work when we run the app in debug-mode, but when we start the app on itself (packaging with `electron-packager . --platform=win32 --overwrite`),
some folders of the azure-storage node_moduls are missing (`md5-wrapper` and `request-wrapper`).

### The problem

The app throws an error

> Uncaught Error: Cannot find module '../md5-wrapper'

in the module.js.

If we simply insert the two folders with copy and paste in the standalone app, everything works fine.

Why aren't the two folders missing? Every oder Package is complete, just these two are missing.

To reproduce the error, just use [the sample-project from here](https://github.com/electron/electron-quick-start) and add an javascript file in the index.html, which has the line

```
var azure = require('azure-storage');
```

EDIT:
 The Code I use to download the BLOB is:

```
var azure = require('azure-storage');
var blobService = azure.createBlobServiceWithSas(blobUri, SAS_TOKEN);
blobService.getBlobToStream('folder', 
     'file.zip', 
     fs.createWriteStream(DESTINATION_PATH+'\\file.zip'), 
     function(error, result, response) {//finished});
```

node -v prints `v6.4.0`

Comment: Can't reproduce your problem on my side. I just download a blob to local file and it works without error. My node version:8.9.3. Could you offer some details about how you get blob from azure?

Comment: @JerryLiu I edited my question. Meanwhile it worked on a different computer, but i'm still interested in the 'why?'